# Having an issue creating a NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, json, nested, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am creating a calendar that links up with a google calendar using google's API. I found a great calendar I can use off of Github. I am now converting the JSON data I receive from the google API into a format suitable for the calendar view from GitHub.

I need to store a NSObject, inside of a NSArray, inside of a NSDictionary, inside of a NSDictionary.

NSObject- A small NSObject that stores title, description, dates, etc.

NSArray- stores all of the NSObjects (line above)

NSDictionary (First One)- stores the NSArray (line above) as the object and the month of the original object as the key

NSDictionary (Second One)- stores the "Months Dictionary" (line above) as the object and the original object as the key.

As of right now, it will add the correct year's in the "Year Dictionary" but will not store the other data correctly.

here is my code, this code will be run for every event in a for loop in a different method.

```
ATEvent *event = [ATEvent new];
event.title = eventGiven[@"summary"];
event.summary = eventGiven[@"description"];
[event compileStartDate:eventGiven[@"start"]];
[event compileEndDate:eventGiven[@"end"]];
event.location = eventGiven[@"location"];

NSCalendar *defaultCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [defaultCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:date]; // Get necessary date components

NSString *month = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)[components month]];
NSString *year = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)[components year]];

NSMutableDictionary *yearDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dataByDate];
NSMutableDictionary *monthDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:yearDictionary[month]];
NSMutableArray *monthArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:monthDictionary[month]];

[yearDictionary setObject:monthDictionary forKey:year];
[monthDictionary setObject:monthArray forKey:month];
[monthArray addObject:event];

NSLog(@"%@",yearDictionary);

dataByDate = yearDictionary;
```

Thanks, I have spent hours staring, thinking of this all logically and don't understand where I'm going wrong! :|

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to build your year and month dictionaries for storing events, you don't want to re-create them each time an event comes in. You need to create the dictionaries (one year and twelve month dictionaries I assume) outside of the event processing loop. You also want to create an empty array to store the events Then you want to add each event into the array for the appropriate month and appropriate year.